# Array value doesn't match substring comparison (batch script)

Tags: arrays, batch-file, if-statement, substring, expansion

I have the following code script:

```
set "file=%cd%/Config.mak"
set /a i=0
set /a j=0

@REM Delete the file if it currently exists in the folder:
IF EXIST Disabled_Features.txt del /F Disabled_Features.txt
@REM If the file can't be deleted, exit with an error:
IF EXIST Disabled_Features.txt exit 1

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions

@REM Parse Features from Config.xml into string array.
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%file%") do (
    call set /a i+=1
    call set Feature[%i%]=%%a
)   

@REM Regexr parametre
call set "search=:=$"

@REM Keep the Disabled Features into new array for stripping module:
for /L %%N in (1,1,%i%) do (
    echo(!Feature[%%N]!|findstr /R /C:"%search%">nul && (
        call echo FOUND
        call set /A j+=1
        call set Feature_Disabled[%j%]=!Feature[%%N]:~0,-2!
        call echo.!Feature_Disabled[%j%]!>>Disabled_Features.txt
    ) || (
        call echo NOT FOUND 
    )
) 
endlocal
```

I was able to print and acces the first `"for"` instruction array values, so it means they are correctly gathered from the file, but when it comes to the second `"for"` instruction, the instruction `!Feature[%%N]!` doesn't seem to pass a correct value to the `findstr`, since the regular expression is `':=$'`, which matches the characters `':='` at the end of the line, and the array values are of the form:

```
EXAMPLE_SAMPLE1:=x5
EXAMPLE_SAMPLE2:=
EXAMPLE_SAMPLE3:=asdadasd
```

So in this case the `findstr` should match the second value of the string array.

Whenever I try the command (to debug):

```
 call echo.!Feature[%%N]!
```

the output shows:

```
!Feature[1]!
```

Any pointing to a proper solution for this?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: My expansion ia already set

Comment: when you want to use delayed expansion you need to enclose variables like this `!variable!` instead `%variable%`

Comment: Use either `set "Feature[!i!]=%%a"` or `call set "Feature[%%i%%]=%%a"` (the latter one does not require enabled delayed expansion).

Comment: Your method should work. If you want to test that the last two chars in the array elements be `:=`, then it is _much_ simpler to use: `if "!Feature[%%N]:~-2!" equ ":=" ( then part ) else ...`. You may also eliminate most `call` commands, excepting in `call set Feature[%%i%%]=%%a` line with _double_ percent signs (as JosefZ indicated), but you may use `!i!` here and the same with `[%j%]` below. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990).

Comment: Thanks, if you post it as an answer I'll mark it as correct.